# choosing a value from select

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

using **ember.js 1.0** and **ember-data 1.0 beta2**

I have a model (state) with the following properties

```
state: DS.attr('string'),
stateName: DS.attr('string'),
```

and a model (customer) with the following properties

```
name: DS.attr('string'),
stateID: DS.attr('string'),
state: DS.belongsTo("state")
```

I want to be able to edit the customer and choose the state from a drop-down (that has the stateID + name showing : eg "FL - Florida" and when selected, to store the state.stateID into the customer.stateID property

this is the first time I've tried something like this , and am slightly confused about the process.

In my customer route I've set up the following:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.controllerFor('state').set('content', this.store.find('state'));
}
```

and my select is this:

```
{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="controllers.state.content"
   optionValuePath="content.stateName"
   optionLabelPath="content.stateName" 
   valueBinding="content.stateID"
   selectionBinding="content.stateID"
   prompt="Select a state"
}}
```

now I'm confused about where to go from here.

thanks

**update**

changed the view to say

```
{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="controllers.state.content"
   optionValuePath="content.stateID"
   optionLabelPath="content.stateName"
   valueBinding="customer.stateID"
}}
```

and I still don't get the stateid property to change . I've also tried

```
selectionBinding="customer"
```

to no avail.

**update #2**

I suspect that my problem may be linked to the property name. I changed the customer.stateID property to be customer.foobar and changed the select to read

```
{{view Ember.Select
  contentBinding="controllers.state.content"
  optionValuePath="content.stateName"
  optionLabelPath="content.stateName"
  valueBinding="foobar"
  class="form-control"

}}
```

and now customer.foobar is updated with the value from the select.

Is there a problem with a property called stateID on customer ? I have a state model and state controller etc so is there a conflict ?

Comment: Can you post a jsbin or fiddle explaining your problem ?

Comment: I am really struggling to get a small working sample. JS newbie here :(

Answer (score 1):

after all that - the problem was in the models themselves. The state model does not have a stateID field, it's state.state ...

My heartfelt apologies to all that wasted their time on this. Such a stupid error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, maybe not the best solution, but it works well:

```
App.ItemModalController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  content: [],

  availableCategories: function() {
    return this.store.find('category');
  }.property(),

  //...
});
```

And the select:

```
{{view Ember.Select
  contentBinding="availableCategories"
  valueBinding="categorySelected"
  optionLabelPath="content.title"
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  prompt="Please select a category"
  class="form-control"
}}
```

Comment: sorry for being dense, but how is this different from my code ? In your model, is "categorySelected" a property of another mode ? I am so new at JS sometimes I feel that I am swimming against the tide as the simple things seem to difficult to achieve

Comment: 'categorySelected' is an "identifier", like the value property in an {{input value=title}}. You can use this.get('categorySelected') in your controller.

Comment: so what I am trying to achieve is that when the user selects a state, the customer.state set to state.id. If I set valueBinding="customer.state" then the customer.state is _not_ updated